# Does a number have to be factored completely to determine if it's smooth?

Tags: prime-factorization

For example, the number $6000$ - does it have to be completely factored to determine if it is 5-smooth? Or is there a shortcut without finding all the prime factors?

Comment: Well, to see whether a number is $B$-smooth, divide out all primes $\leqslant B$, and if there is something left, it isn't $B$-smooth, if you get to $1$, it is. For small $B$, that's not much work.

Comment: @DanielFischer You're completely right...I forgot about that.

Comment: Well, in principle you could precompute $L(N_{\text{max}}) = \prod_{p\leq B}p^{\lfloor\log_p N_{\text{max}}\rfloor}$ and test whether $N$ divides $L(N_{\text{max}})$, but the complexity of that approach grows about as fast as that of trial division, which is simpler.